# LibGDX Fixed timestep gameloop with interpolation using ashley

Tags: libgdx, interpolation, game-loop

I have a question because I am not 100% sure if I understood it correctly. My question is regarding a **fixed timestep game loop with interpolation**.

I made a small test program and it seems to work but I am not sure if it is correct (**see code snippets below**).

I created two entities next to each other on the y-axis with a speed of 1000 and I can see a clear "stuttering" with the non-interpolated entity while the interpolated one moves very smoothly.

My question is if my interpolation is correct though. I am saving the **previous position of the entity each frame and interpolate it towards the real current position**. Is this correct or should the interpolation work against the future next position?

I hope you understand what I mean :)

Thanks for your help!

Regards
Simon

P.S.: Also the warning with Family.all(...) is annoying and I have to use suppresswarning which i personally do not like. Is there a correct way to call it without warnings?
**edit: Solved - the reason was I had sourceCompatibility to Java 1.6. I set it now to Java 1.8 and the warnings did go away (I think this was already solved with Java 1.7)**

```
// position component
public class PositionComponent implements Component {
  public Vector2 position       = new Vector2(0, 0);
  public Vector2 previousPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

// speed component
public class SpeedComponent implements Component {
  public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

// movement system to update position according to speed
public class MovementSystem extends IteratingSystem {
  private final ComponentMapper<SpeedComponent>    speedMapper;
  private final ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> positionMapper;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public MovementSystem() {
    super(Family.all(PositionComponent.class, SpeedComponent.class).get());
    speedMapper = ComponentMapper.getFor(SpeedComponent.class);
    positionMapper = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
    final PositionComponent positionComponent = positionMapper.get(entity);
    final SpeedComponent speedComponent = speedMapper.get(entity);

    positionComponent.previousPosition.set(positionComponent.position);
    positionComponent.position.add(speedComponent.speed.x * deltaTime, speedComponent.speed.y * deltaTime);
  }
}

// render method of libgdx screen
// fixedPhysicsStep = 1.0f / 25.0f = 25fps
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
  if (delta > fixedPhysicsStep) {
    delta = fixedPhysicsStep;
  }

  accumulator += delta;
  while (accumulator >= fixedPhysicsStep) {
    world.update(fixedPhysicsStep);
    accumulator -= fixedPhysicsStep;
  }

  renderer.render(accumulator / fixedPhysicsStep);
}

// the renderer render method that renders the first entity 
// with interpolation using lerp and the second entity without interpolation
public void render(float alpha) {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  batch.begin();
  for (int i = 0; i < entities.size; ++i) {
    final Entity entity = entities.get(i);
    final PositionComponent posComp = positionComponentMapper.get(entity);

    if (i == 0) {
      posComp.previousPosition.lerp(posComp.position, alpha);
      batch.draw(img, posComp.previousPosition.x, posComp.previousPosition.y);
    } else {
      batch.draw(img, posComp.position.x, posComp.position.y);
    }
  }
  batch.end();
}
```

Comment: That is the way it is suggested in the legendary Gaffer On Games article. It does result in up to one physics step of lag at all times. Depending on the game type and size of your physics step, it may not be perceptible. I suppose you could try extrapolating forward (add one to the alpha you use for interpolating). Depending on the the game that might cause jittering whenever the player presses an input. Why are you clamping delta down to the physics step size?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

The reason for clamping delta to the physics step has no special meaning. I thought it can be an arbitrary number because I did not see anywhere a special explanation and sometimes I saw 0.25 but I also saw 0.04 and 0.01.
So I thought why not just using a constant that I already have.

Is there a recommended fps / clamping delta value for RPG based games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Tenfour04 for the details. I did some final adjustments and for me it looks very smooth now. The things I changed:
- Override the render method of the Game instance to use **getRawDeltaTime** instead of getDeltaTime because getDeltaTime averages the time between frames instead of using the raw value
- Instead of clamping delta by the physics step I use now 0.25. No special reason but seems like a lot of people are using this value
- Instead of using lerp for the interpolation I am using now the **interpolate** method with Interpolation **smoother**

After changing those three things (and changing the physics step to 60fps) it seems very smooth for me.